# How do I insert local variable MySQL using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```java
public class DataBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company", , )) {
            Type[] types = { new GraphicCard(), new HardDrive(), new Keyboard(), new Memory(), new Monitor(), new Mouse(), new Processor() };
            Product product = new Product(10, types);
            Range rangeUnitPrice = new Range(10_000, 220_000);
            Range rangeQuantity = new Range(0, 20);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            while (product.getNumberOfEntery() > 0) {
                String typeAndCatagory = product.getRandomType();
                String name = product.getName(typeAndCatagory);
                String description = product.getDescription();
                double unit_Price = product.randomUnit_PriceGenerator(name, 'x', rangeUnitPrice);
                int quantity_In_Stock = product.generateQuantity_In_Stock(rangeQuantity);
                String brand = product.getRandomBrand();
                System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", " + "Type: " + typeAndCatagory + ", " + "Random price: " + unit_Price + ", " + "Quantity in stock: " + quantity_In_Stock + ", " + "Random brand: " + brand);
                String query = "INSERT INTO product VALUES (" + name + ", " + description + ", " + unit_Price + ", " + quantity_In_Stock + ", " + brand + ", " + typeAndCatagory + ", " + typeAndCatagory + ")";
                statement.executeUpdate(query);
                product.decreasesNumberOfEntrees();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The query doesn't work, and the first value is the default (PRIMARY KEY AUTO-INCREMENT), which I don't need to specify. The error is below

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near '10 AMD graphic card Gamer Edition, ,
> 180657.63138583858, 6, HP, Graphic Card, Gr' at line 1

Comment: "*the query doesn't work*" - What does "*does not work*" mean? Please [edit] the question and describe what the expected and observed behaviour is.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 AMD graphic card Gamer Edition, , 180657.63138583858, 6, HP, Graphic Card, Gr' at line 1

Comment: Please [edit] your question...

Comment: Use bind parameters. And look at your query. One your values is nothing.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can u please explain, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @BillKarwin my table works fine, I already did many modifications on the database and the tables, I don't want to debug I would like to insert values to the specific table in a database, that's it, just how to insert local variable to the executeUpdate methods, that's all i need

Comment: @MohrezaKh `Edition, , 180657.63138583858` What value is there between `Edition` and `180657.63138583858`? Also, none of your char values are quoted. You should use a `PreparedStatement` and **bind parameters**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You format a string in this line to use as an SQL statement:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO product VALUES (" + name + ", " + description + ", " + unit_Price + ", " + quantity_In_Stock + ", " + brand + ", " + typeAndCatagory + ", " + typeAndCatagory + ")";
```

Something is wrong with this statement that makes it produce a syntax error. What is wrong?

It's difficult to debug this by staring at the Java expression. It's confusing to look at all the `"` and `+` and see what's wrong.

It would be easier to see what's wrong if you can see the final result of the string, not the Java expression that builds a string.

So before you execute it, try printing it out:

```
System.out.println(query);
```

Then the problem may be more clearly visible.

I predict it will look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (10 AMD graphic card Gamer Edition, , 180657.63138583858, 6, HP, Graphic Card, Gr...
```

This is missing quotes around the string values in your VALUES clause. It's not valid SQL.

The best solution is to learn to use query parameters. Then you don't have to worry about quotes around values. And the code is more secure from SQL injection.

In your case, something like the following:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO product VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
Statement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
while (product.getNumberOfEntery() > 0) {

    // set the values for all your variables...

    statement.setString(1, name);
    statement.setString(2, description);
    statement.setDouble(3, unit_Price);
    statement.setInt(4, quantity_In_Stock);
    statement.setString(5, brand);
    statement.setString(6, typeAndCatagory);
    statement.setString(7, typeAndCatagory);
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Many thx for your answer, what happens if the first element is PRIMARY KEY AUTO _INCREMENT put ? or don't put anything

Comment: If you have an auto-increment column, either use `NULL` for that column (not a `?` placeholder), or else spell out which columns your INSERT will set values for, and omit the auto-increment column.

Comment: Now i am getting this  error :java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: That error message is typical if you list columns in the INSERT statement but have a different number of elements in the VALUES clause. Example: `INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`. See? Two columns named, but three values. The lists of columns and values have to have the same length.

Comment: MySQL supports an alternative INSERT syntax that helps make it easier to ensure each column and value is matched: `INSERT INTO mytable SET col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ?;` This is not standard SQL syntax supported by other brands, but MySQL supports it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The major one is, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. You will have to enclose the text values withing single quotes yourself.

The solution to both the problem is [using `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) as shown below:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO product VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    //...
    
    pstmt.setString(1, name);
    pstmt.setString(2, description);
    pstmt.setDouble(3, unit_Price);
    //...

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Also, I suggest you always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. `unit_Price` should be named as `unitPrice`.

Comment: Many thx for your answer, what happens if the first element is PRIMARY KEY AUTO _INCREMENT put ? or don't put anything

Comment: @MohrezaKh - Do not put `?` for that column inside `VALUES` i.e. inside `VALUES`, put only those parameters for which you want to insert a value in the DB; and not for the ones which are updated automatically. Note that for each `?`, you will have to use `pstmt.set...`. Another thing you need to understand is that in the method call,  `pstmt.setString(1,...)`, `1` refers to the first `?` and not the first column in your table. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: It doesn't give an error anymore, but I can't see the inserts on my MYSQL workbench

Comment: If the inserts are not appearing, that's a different question. Maybe you are not committing the transaction?

Comment: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExcepti
 ... 9 more

Comment: now I am getting this error: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1